# Calculating line integral of a vector field

Tags: calculus, line-integrals

I already know how to calculate line integral of a vector field, but in a textbook (calculus by Ron Larson) i have seen equation $\int_C F.N ds$ ,which 'C' is integration path, 'F' is vector field and 'N' is unit normal vector of integration path and integration path has been represented by a vector valued function with parameter of arc length. So i have got a bit confused because i believe, instead of normal vector 'N', we should use unit tangent vector 'T'.
How to Calculate line integral of a vector field when integration path has been represented by a vector valued function with parameter of arc length?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the plane here, integrating $F\cdot N$ or $F\cdot T$ depends on our application. Both are used. For instance, if $C$ is a circle, then the integral of $F\cdot N$ says something about how much three field "radiates" out of or into the disc bounded by $C$, while the integral of $F\cdot T$ says something about how much the field rotates.

Comment: Something to think about... there is not a unique tangent vector at any point on a surface.  But as Arthur points out $F\cdot T$ and $F\cdot N$ are measuring different things.

Answer (score 0):

This is your typical line integral used for things like work: $$\int_C \mathbf F \cdot \, \mathrm d \mathbf r = \int_C \mathbf F \cdot \mathbf T \, \mathrm d s$$

Integrating the unit normal, however, gives the flux along a line: $$\int_C \mathbf F \cdot \mathbf N \, \mathrm d s$$